# Accessing elements in single Json Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a book in the form of a single Json object returned from an ajax request:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "bytes": 2598,
  "book": {
    "isbn": 9781449397227,
    "title": "jQuery Pocket Reference",
    "author": "David Flanagan",
    "description": "As someone who uses jQuery on a regular basis, blah blah.",
    "published": "2000-05-02",
    "cover": "http://bks9.books.google.co.uk/books?id=rK6YPwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
    "pages": 402,
  }
}
```

And I wish to access the isbn, title, author elements etc to append to my output . My question is how to access these in my

```
success: function(data) {

};
```

I have used console.log(data); in success and Firebug shows me that the data is there. My other ajax calls return a books array and I can just use something like:

```
$.each(data.books, function(i,book)
```

and it works fine. But with the example above its just a single object 'book'.

Thanks

Comment: When you look into Firebug when in `success` function, how does your `data` object look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: function(data) {
 console.log(data.book.isbn);
 console.log(data.book.title);
 console.log(data.book.author);
};
```

Comment: Many thanks, it was data.book.item required. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem (because of my little english). But if your ajax call has `dataType:'json',` you can access the data with

```
success: function(data) {
    console.info(data)
```

otherwise you have to parse the data with

```
success: function(data) {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

or in case use are using Crockford JSON lib

```
success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
```